# Операторы вывода данных

Tags: pascal

Подскажите, какие варианты оператора Write в Паскале есть.
Например, варианты:
`Write, Writeln, WriteForm` считаются разными.
Перечислите все такие варианты для досконального изучения.

Comment: @platinumsemen, здесь не неиссякаемый источник азбучных знаний. Поищите пожалуйста в гугле (ну пожалуйста:)

Comment: А цель в чем?

Comment: @Asen чтобы изучить каждый вариант оператора Write, вы просто напишите их названия, а я нагуглю инфу

Comment: Быть может лучше задать вопрос с другой стороны т. е.: "Как при помощи оператора Write сделать..."

Comment: Кстати, это не операторы. Go Read The Fine Manual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Досконально, значит. Ну тогда читайте стандарты [ISO7185](http://www.standardpascal.org/iso7185.pdf) и [ISO10260](http://www.standardpascal.org/iso10206.pdf).

Кстати, никакой процедуры WriteForm вы там не найдете. Очевидно, это нестандартное расширение, присутствующее только в используемом вами диалекте. Поэтому рекомендую взять лучше хорошую книгу по алгоритмам и свой энтузиазм, которого, судя по стилю вопросов, вам не занимать, направить в действительно полезное русло.